# Using populate in form completion

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I use mongoose 4.11.10, I declared 2 models: User & Task. My User model is:

```
let UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 1,
    maxlength: 15
  }
});
let User = mongoose.model("UserModel", UserSchema);
```

The fragment from User model:

```
let TaskSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  userName: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
    required: false,
    minlength: [1, "Invalid name"],
    maxlength: [15, "Too big name"]
  }
});
let Task = mongoose.model("TaskModel", TaskSchema);
```

I´ve got form, where I input all these values:

```
<p>Add new task: </p>
<form action="/api/tasks/" method="post">
  Name:
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <br>
  Definition:
  <input type="text" name="definition">
  <br>
  Status:
  <input type="text" name="status">
  <br>
  Responsible user:
  <input type="text" name="userName">
  <br>
  Deadline:
  <input type="date" name="deadline" >
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="SEND">
</form>
```

On the server-side I´ve got controller:

```
api.post("/tasks/", (req, res) => {
  let name = req.body.name;
  let definition = req.body.definition;
  let status = req.body.status;
  let userName = req.body.userName;
  let deadline = req.body.deadline;
  if (userName.length < 1) {
    Task.create({name: name}, {definition: definition}, {status: status}, {userName: "not delegated yet"}, {deadline: deadline})
      .then(() => {
        console.log("Insertion successful");
        res.redirect("/api/tasks");
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log("Cannot insert");
        throw err;
      })
  } else {
    Task.create({name: name}, {definition: definition}, {status: status}, {userName: userName}, {deadline: deadline})
      .then(() => Task.findOne({name: name}).populate("userName"))
      .then(() => {
        console.log("Insertion successful");
        res.redirect("/api/tasks");
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log("Cannot insert");
        throw err;
      })
  }
});
```

As you can see, I want to link 2 schemas: I want to "delegate" task on a specified user, but now populate() mongoose method does not work :( How can I solve that issue?

**Any help will be appreciated!**

Answer (score 0):

You defined the type of `userName` as an [ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) but the type of `name` is a String. That is a mismatch and population won't work.

Change the type to `String`.

```
let TaskSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    user: {
        type: String,
        ref: 'User',
        required: false,
        minlength: [1, "Invalid name"],
        maxlength: [15, "Too big name"]
    }
});
```

I suggest you rename `userName` to `user` to add more clarity when you query

```
Task.findOne(...).populate('user').exec(function (err, task) {
    console.log(task.user.name);
});
```

If you are trying to get all the tasks for a particular user without adding a `tasks` array to your schema, you could use [virtual population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate-virtuals)

```
UserSchema.virtual('tasks', {
    ref: 'Task', // The model to use
    localField: 'name', // Find task where `localField`
    foreignField: 'user' // is equal to `foreignField`
});
```

And you can then do

```
User.findOne(...).populate('tasks').exec(function (err, user) {
    console.log(user.tasks);
});
```